Invalid argument error when adding Required Reviewer via Azure DevOps API
I can add myself as a Required Reviewer on a Pull Request in Azure DevOps without any issues. However, when I attempt to do this using the API, I encounter the following error:
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid argument value.\r\nParameter name: A valid reviewer must be supplied.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer.InvalidArgumentValueException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer","typeKey":"InvalidArgumentValueException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

I tried the following reviewerId:

emailadress user@domain.com
Object ID of my user in Entra ID
Looked up the ID in https://dev.azure.com/some/project/_apis/git/repositories/blabla-1/pullRequests/1/reviewers/
I've also tried the ID retrieved from Teams using post Azure Devops REST API add reviewer to a PR to "Get Team Members With Extended Properties" with no luck


How did you set the request body when calling the API?

You can do like as below:

Use the Azure DevOps REST API "Identities - Read Identities" to get the ID of user that needs to be added as a PR reviewer.

Use the Azure DevOps REST API "Pull Request Reviewers - Create Pull Request Reviewer" to add the user as a required reviewer on the specified PR.


Below is a sample of PowerShell script to show how to call these two REST API.
$organization = "xxxx"  # The name of Azure DevOps organization.
$userMailAddress = "xxxx"  # The user email address that needs to be added as a PR reviewer.
$project = "xxxx"  # The name of project where the git repository is.
$repository = "xxxx"  # The name of git repository where the PR is.
$pullRequestId = 1111  # The ID of PR.

$pat = "xxxx"  # The Personal Access Token.
$base64Token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $base64Token"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Get the user ID.
$uri_read_id = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/${organization}/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue=${userMailAddress}&queryMembership=None&api-version=7.1"
$user_id = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri_read_id -Headers $headers).value[0].id

# Add the user as a required reviewer on the specified PR.
$uri_add_pr_reviewer = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/git/repositories/${repository}/pullRequests/${pullRequestId}/reviewers/${user_id}?api-version=7.1"

$body_add_pr_reviewer = @{
    id = $user_id
    isRequired = $True
    vote = 0
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $uri_add_pr_reviewer -Headers $headers -Body $body_add_pr_reviewer


EDIT:
To get add a group/team as the reviewer on a PR, you also can use the API "Identities - Read Identities" to get the ID of the group/team, and use the API "Pull Request Reviewers - Create Pull Request Reviewer" to add the it as PR reviewer.
To get the ID of a group/team, you can pass the subject descriptor of it to the API "Identities - Read Identities". This method also can get the ID of a user.
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/identities?subjectDescriptors={subjectDescriptors}&queryMembership=None&api-version=7.1


You can go to "Project Settings" (or "Organization Settings") > "Permissions" > "Groups" to get the subject descriptor of a group/team.


Similarly, you can go to "Project Settings" (or "Organization Settings") > "Permissions" > "Users" to get the subject descriptor of a user.



The sample of PowerShell script to call the API.
$subjectDescriptor = "xxxx"  # The subject descriptor of user, group or team that needs to be added as a PR reviewer.
$organization = "xxxx"  # The name of Azure DevOps organization.
$project = "xxxx"  # The name of project where the git repository is.
$repository = "xxxx"  # The name of git repository where the PR is.
$pullRequestId = 1111  # The ID of PR.

$pat = "xxxx"  # The Personal Access Token.
$base64Token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $base64Token"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Get the ID of user, group or team.
$uri_read_id = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/${organization}/_apis/identities?subjectDescriptors=${subjectDescriptor}&queryMembership=None&api-version=7.1"
$reviewer_id = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri_read_id -Headers $headers).value[0].id

# Add the user, group or team as a required reviewer on the specified PR.
$uri_add_pr_reviewer = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/git/repositories/${repository}/pullRequests/${pullRequestId}/reviewers/${reviewer_id}?api-version=7.1"

$body_add_pr_reviewer = @{
    id = $reviewer_id
    isRequired = $True
    vote = 0
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $uri_add_pr_reviewer -Headers $headers -Body $body_add_pr_reviewer



This seems to roll up to the User Object ID that I've used in Entra ID as well. However, the issue remains the same. Am I missing something here?

@Vir, Based on my attempt and check, the user ID returned from the API "Identities - Read Identities" is not the Object ID of the specified user displayed in the Microsoft Entra ID tenant on Azure Portal. So, it might not work to directly copy the Object ID of the user from Azure Portal to call the API "Pull Request Reviewers - Create Pull Request Reviewer".

@Vir, In addition, ensure the PAT (Personal Access Token) you use to call the API has the scopes Code (Read & write) and Identity (Read) at least.

I've created a PAT with full access, ran the script and used the ID that was in the ouput, however still no luck. The json payload contains the properties: id, isRequired = true, isFlagged = false. Am I missing something here? Also it is an Patch operation.

I need to use PUT instead of PATCH. The Microsoft Doc says PATCH, should be PUT. Thank you for sharing your code Bright Ran-MSFT!

Now I seem to be able to add a user, however, how do I add a Group?

@Vir, The linked docs of API "Pull Request Reviewers - Create Pull Request Reviewer"   in my answer is the Microsoft official docs. From the docs, you can see the request method is PUT not PATCH. About adding a group as a PR reviewer, I have updated my answer with more suggestions (See EDIT).

@Vir, Have your tried the latest PowerShell script shared above? Is it working for you to add user and group as PR reviewer?

Yes, thank you! It works now. I indeed saw in your powershell script it was a PUT and tried that. Secondly, the reason why I couldn't find the Object ID, was because it was a DevOps group, so not a group in Entra ID (No Cloud Group or Windows Server AD). I found it through the REST API, same way/URL that you've shared. Many thanks!
Last issue now is that there is a throttled limit, the function is running every 15 minutes, but I can't find the cap in the docs.
